# finding Linux distro with terminal only

Tags: linux

I'n looking to download a linux distro that has nothing but a terminal, simply boot up  the machine into a console/terminal that runs sh/bash.
I want it to test some shell script and I really don't need a desktop environment because I want it to perform as best as possible.
If anyone knows anything like this let me know thanks!

I tried to look it up on google and YT and all I find is some lightweight distributions but with desktops.

Comment: A docker container?

Comment: I really have little to no experience in dockers.
Can I install a docker image on a kali vm and have that image run only the terminal ?

Comment: yeah, you can just launch some base container [e.g.](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=&type=image) theres Alpine Linux image that claims to be only 5 Mb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you Arch Linux. It's a lightweight and DIY distro. You don't need a desktop environment to install it on your system